# Operações entre várias classes

Tags: java, classes, java-8, superclasse

Boas, sou relativamente novo à programação em Java! É o seguinte tenho uma Classe Super de nome User da qual existem 2 subclasses Citizen e Autarchy, dentro da classe Citizen tenho criada uma ArrayList que irá guarda os Prizes desse citizen, esses prizes iram ser inseridos nessa lista pelo Autarchy sendo que tenho também uma classe Prize da qual irei criar várias instancias de prizes para atribuir aos citizens como devo proceder para que os Autarchy possam dar os prémios aos Citizen?

```
    package Users;


    public class User {
private String name;
private String password;
private String email;

public User(String name, String password, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
}

//public receiveEmail(this.email) function to email a confirmation email to the user


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}


}
```

---

```
package Users;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Citizen extends User{
private ArrayList prizes = new ArrayList<>();

public Citizen(String name, String password, String email) {
    super(name, password, email);
}

public ArrayList getPrizes() {
    return this.prizes;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name:  " + this.getName() + " | Password:  " + this.getPassword() +" | E-mail:  " + this.getEmail() + " | prizes:  " + this.prizes;
}
```

---

```
package Users;

public class Prize{
private String name;
private String description;
private int value;

public Prize(String name, String description, int value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Achievment: " + this.name;
}
```

Comment: Mas todos os `Cizitens` são `Users` ? Parece um pouco estranha essa modelação. E deve sempre utilizar `ArrayList` genérico, que no caso da sua classe `Citizen` ficaria `private ArrayList<Prize> prizes`

Comment: Sim todos os Citizens e Autarchy seram Users da app, apenas teram diferentes funcionalidades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem diversas maneiras. Você poderia escrever um método para sua classe Citizen, por exemplo:

```
public receivePrize(Prize newPrize) {
    if(prize != NULL)
        prizes.add(prize);
}
```

e em sua classe Autarchy:

```
public givePrize(Citizen winner) { 
    winner.receivePrize(takePrize());
}

private Prize takePrize() {
    Prize prize = NULL;
    if (prizes.size() > 0) {
        prize = prizes.get(prizes.size() - 1);
        prizes.remove(prizes.size() - 1);
    } else {
        System.out.print("Sorry there are no more prizes\n");
    }
    return prize;
}
```

Comment: Se eu inserir esses métodos nas minhas classes ele fica dizendo que "there is no default constructor in Users.User", alguma sugestão Luciano?

Comment: Tente criar um construtor padrão em User: `public User(){}`